# How to use underscore throttle for scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, underscore.js

I was trying to use underscore library throttle function for my div scroll.

Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/arunslb123/ffxhn0xg/

Click left and right arrow for div scroll.

My code :

```
$("#lft-arrow").click(function () {
 var leftPos = $('#numWrap').scrollLeft();
 $("#numWrap").stop().animate({scrollLeft: leftPos - 200}, 800);
});

$("#rgt-arrow").click(function () {
 var leftPos = $('#numWrap').scrollLeft();
 $("#numWrap").stop().animate({scrollLeft: leftPos + 200}, 800);
});
```

My code for throttle :

```
function leftArrow(){
 var leftPos = $('#numWrap').scrollLeft();
 $("#numWrap").stop().animate({scrollLeft: leftPos - 200}, 800);
}

function rightArrow(){
 var leftPos = $('#numWrap').scrollLeft();
 $("#numWrap").stop().animate({scrollLeft: leftPos + 200}, 800);
}


var throttledLeft = _.throttle(leftArrow, 100);
var throttledRight=_.throttle(rightArrow,100);



$("#lft-arrow").click(function () {
 $("#numWrap").scroll(throttledLeft);
});

$("#rgt-arrow").click(function () {
 $("#numWrap").scroll(throttledRight);
});
```

How to use _throttle here?

Comment: Seems to work for me. What is the problem you are having?

Comment: @JackZelig In that JsFiddle, I have not used _throttle. I want to use throttle function to handle the scroll. Just comment the code in "My code section" and add the "My code for throttle" code. Now the scroll is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question.

The problem is the wait time in throttle function should be greater than animate function.

Here is my updated code :

```
var leftArrow=function(){
 var leftPos = $('#numWrap').scrollLeft();
 $("#numWrap").animate({scrollLeft: leftPos - 200}, 800);
}

var  rightArrow=function(){
 var leftPos = $('#numWrap').scrollLeft();
 $("#numWrap").animate({scrollLeft: leftPos + 200}, 800);
}

$("#lft-arrow").click(_.throttle(leftArrow,1000));
$("#rgt-arrow").click(_.throttle(rightArrow,1000));
```